# Different probabilities with ten dice

Tags: probability, dice

Given 10 dice:

1. What probability do I have to throw ten dice, so that the sum of each gives 24?

   - I have no idea how to calculate this one as simple as possible.
2. What are the chances of $3$ dice in a row $(1, 2, 3)$, $(2, 3, 4)$, $(3, 4, 5)$, $(4, 5, 6)$? (You throw $10$ dice and at least $3$ of them have to be the triplets.)

   - Can this be calculated by saying $4 \times \left({1\over6}\right)^7$, since we have four combinations, each requiring $3$ given digits?
3. What are the chances of $5$ dice in a row $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)$ or $(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)$

   - Analogous to the above problem, I suggest $2 \times \left({1\over6}\right)^5$.
4. What are the chances of a pair $(1, 1)$, $(2, 2)$, $(3, 3)$, $(4, 4)$, $(5, 5)$, $(6, 6)$?

   - Since there are $10$ dice, this should be $100\%$. Or not?
5. What are the chances of two, three, or four pairs (separately)?

   - Since there are $10$ dice, you always have $4$ pairs, right?
6. What are the chances of one, two or three "drillings" (three of the same value)?

   - The first die can be any of $6$ options, then two are a fixed option, and the rest are, again, one of $6$ options. I think the answer should then be $\left({1\over6}\right)^7$.
7. What are the chances of rolling seven dice with the same value?

   - I think this is $\left({1\over6}\right)^7$.

Comment: As you are new to the site:  people here tend to not respond well (or at all) to questions like this that appear to be routine homework problems and which show absolutely no effort.  Rather than post your homework here for us to do for you, why not take one of these questions (any one, really) and try it yourself?  If you post your efforts on one of these, people will meet you half way.

Comment: I've already worked on around twenty of other questions, this are the ones I'm having trouble with. I mean can you ask on stack overflow questions of the type "is the following calculation true?" if yes, I can provide things I answered, but not sure if I answered them correctly.

Comment: To improve your question, you can show your working for these questions. You can also  provide [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) by indicating where these questions come from, or maybe give some of the other questions which you have already completed.

Comment: Edited and added what I have.

Comment: For (2), do the dice have to be thrown in order? Or do you mean among the 10 dice, there exists three dice that form a triplet it some order? Similar questions for (3), (4), (5). For (6), I do not understand what you are looking for at all. For (7), do you need exactly 7 are the same? Or is it at least 7?

Comment: Die is singular; dice is plural; dices is the third person singular form of the verb to dice, meaning to cut into small cubes.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:
 For (1):
Let $x_i$ denote the value rolled on the $i$-th die.

You have $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i = 24$ and $\forall i, 1\le x_i \le 6$.

We can translate this problem to: $$\sum_{i=1}^{10}y_i = 14, \forall i, 0\le y_i \le 5$$

Each solution to this Diophantine Equation maps to an arrangement of dice that add up to 24, and over all possible solutions, you map to all possible arrangements of dice. A single arrangement of dice has probability $\dfrac{1}{6^{10}}$.

I need to think more about problems (2) and (3).

For (4), you are correct. This is the Pigeonhole Principle.

For (5), you need more clarification. Can $(1,1,1)$ be considered three pairs?

I do not understand what you are looking for with problem (6).

For (7):
Assuming you want exactly seven dice that are the same, choose seven of the dice. Choose the value for those dice. The remaining three dice can be any of the other five values.